# How do i access a string that is set by a user in C# console app?

Tags: c#

Im very new to C# and am pretty lost
Im making a simple console app where someone can type their name and request it, but whenever i request it, it doesnt show up. I get no return.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    public class Name
    {
        public string userName;

        public void enterName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your name:");
            userName = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void showName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYour name is " + userName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing how you call these functions how can we know. But looking at the pastebin you link in the comment below (which really should be in your question), you are creating `new Name` on each run of the loop. You need the `name` object to be outside of the loop if you want its value to persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Name name = new Name();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Enter name");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Show name");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Exit");
                char choise = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                if (choise.Equals('1'))
                    name.EnterName(); // calling EnterName function.
                else if (choise.Equals('2'))
                    name.ShowName(); // calling ShowNamefunction.
                else if (choise.Equals('3'))
                    break; // exiting from while
                Console.Clear(); // clearing console
            }
        }
    }
    public class Name
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public void EnterName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your name:");
            UserName = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public void ShowName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYour name is " + UserName);
            Console.ReadKey(); // This is for freezing console. When you are presing any key program will continue.
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use `Name name = new Name();`.

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Enter name");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Show name");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Exit");
                char choise = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                if (choise.Equals('1'))
                    Name.EnterName(); // calling EnterName function.
                else if (choise.Equals('2'))
                    Name.ShowName(); // calling ShowNamefunction.
                else if (choise.Equals('3'))
                    break; // exiting from while
                Console.Clear(); // clearing console
            }
        }
    }
    static public class Name
    {
        static public string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        static public void EnterName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your name:");
            UserName = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static public void ShowName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYour name is " + UserName);
            Console.ReadKey(); // This is for freezing console. When you are presing any key program will continue.
        }
    }
}
```

Here is your comment answer.

```
using System;

namespace NameAndCalc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var menu = new Menu();
            menu.ShowMenu();
            //Show the main menu to the user by looping it as a boolean
        }
    }

    public class Menu
    {
        public void ShowMenu()
        {
            var name = new Name(); // I took off these from inside while
            var sum = new Summation(); // If I didn't take off creating new name and sum every while starts.
            while (true)
            {
                //Physically show user the options in console
                Console.WriteLine("\n1) Enter your name");
                Console.WriteLine("2) Show your name");
                Console.WriteLine("3) Summation");
                Console.WriteLine("4) Exit application");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Select an option: ");

                //Switch case for the boolean menu. User can choose to run different functions or close the app.
                switch (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar)
                {
                    case '1':
                        {
                            name.EnterName();
                            break;
                        }
                    case '2':
                        {
                            name.ShowName();
                            break;
                        }
                    case '3':
                        {
                            sum.SumAndTotal();
                            break;
                        }
                    case '4':
                        return;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Name
    {
        public string userName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public void EnterName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your name:");
            userName = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void ShowName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYour name is " + userName);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Summation
    {
        public void SumAndTotal()
        {
            //Ask user for inputs for summation
            Console.WriteLine("\nWhat is your first number?");
            int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("\nWhat is your second number?");
            int secondNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            //Gives subtotal of the number inputs given by user
            int total = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe subtotal of those two numbers are " + total);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Yes, further explanation would be much appreciated. I tried to fiddle a little with what you wrote as an answer but couldnt quite get it. here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/Lp8npzX8

Comment: By the way, method names start with a capital letter in C#.

Comment: So the reason it didn't work was that I was looping the menu options in the Main method rather than separately in the Menu class?

Comment: Yes. while(true){ menu created and called  } -> menu died -> new menu created and called -> menu died...